# how to load a second datagrid using an action column in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid

I have a datagrid that displays data and a user can select the "view" action column on this datagrid. When this happens, the user should view details of the selected row in a new gridpanel. I am populating a new store for this grid in the action column as follows:

Action Column handler:

```
 //code in action column handler
var store;


console.log ('About to load the store');


var rec = view.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
var rowid = rec.get('ID');

store = Ext.getStore('MetadataJsonPStore').load({
    params:{
        solution: 'DemoDocuments',
        project: 'MyDemoDocuments',
        process : 'RetreiveFileMetadata',
        user :'admin',
        password :'changethis',
        waittofinish :'true' ,
        FileID : rowid
    },

    callback: function(records, options, success) {
        if(success) {
            var fileMetadataPanel = Ext.getCmp('matadataPanel');
            //if (records.length = 0)
            console.log(records[0])
            ;
        }
        else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Request Failed','Service currently not available');
        }
    }//end-callback-function
});
```

My store is correctly populated but my grid doesn't display. When I view my console i do not have errors so i assume i am missing a step.

My datagrid is linked to a store ( the store being loaded above) but the data does not display. Any ideas of how to complete this function?

Comment: Are you sure your grid are correctly linked to your loading store? Try call `getStore()` of grid and check.

Answer (score -1):

You need to refresh that Grid view.

Sencha: [grid view refresh](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-refresh)

```
gridView = this.getCmp('gridID');

grid.refresh();
```

**Other solution**:

Load data on the store2 before render the new grid view

Comment: If you are loading store you don't need to refresh grid, it happens automatically.

Comment: I know that, the grid refresh automatically after load... but maybe its a solution, for that it's my second solution. And I read this to discard your answer type: "My datagrid is linked to a store", but it could be the solutions your answer...